# Get a query_set from an other query_set. Django

Tags: django, django-models

In my django app I have a model "Match", linked to my model "User" with a foreign key. I also have a function that gives me a query_set of "live_matches" (matches that are currently played).

What I try to have is a query_set with all the users of the "live_matches".

Here is my models.py:

```
class LiveMatchManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        now = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
        queryset = super(LiveMatchManager, self).get_query_set()
        return queryset.filter(match__date_start__lte=now, match__date_end__gte=now)

class Match(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    date_end = models.DateTimeField()

# Managers
objects = models.Manager()
live_matches = LiveMatchManager()
```

What I would like to have is a function that gives me a query_set of the users that are linked to a "live_match", and I don't find how to do that.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#returns all users, linked to live_matches
>>>User.objects.filter(match__in=Match.live_matches.all())
[<User: user1>, <User: user2>, <User: user3>]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I just have a question. I have a model UserProfile (a custom Profile), linked to the model User with a OnetoOneField. I would like to have the queryset on the base of UserProfile instead of User (UserProfile.object.filter(...)), keeping the "user = models.ForeignKey(User)". Do you have any idea on how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Try `UserProfile.objects.filter(user__match__in=Match.live_matches.all())`